# Connect java with javascript for data visualization in Browser

Tags: java, javascript

I am working on a project where I access the APIs and get the output using `Java`. Now I want to display the data using some graphs and other data visualization tools in a browser. I have searched for some `JavaScript` libraries for that. But how can I connect java and javascript to get the output in a browser.

Can I do it with `JSP`? I don't want to use applets. Please suggest other ways also.

EDIT: If I use JSP then I will have to host a server. Is there a direct way without hosting a server?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use pure Javascript?

Comment: Am using JAVA to get data from JIRA ( http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview). Jira Java Rest Client makes it easy to get data using JAVA. So I preferred Java

Comment: You can easily access the JIRA REST API with pure JavaScript.

Comment: Java is not an acronym. No need to capitalize.

Comment: Initially I thought of using JavaScript, but couldn't find some starting tutorial so I continued it with Java. Seems like I have to rewrite the whole thing in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that with `JSP(java server page)`. By passing data from Java to javascript in your jsp page. JSP page typically compiled into raw html and send it to client.

Simple example of passing value java to javascript in jsp page.

```
<%
  String str="Hello world";
%>
<script>
 var jsvar = <%=str%>;
</script>
```

A example of java list values to js variable using jsp scriptlet.

```
var  myArray = new Array();
<% for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) { %>
      myArray[<%= i %>] = "<%= list.get(i) %>"; 
<% } %>
```

Better use jstl tag library which is easier to write and structured.

[JSP documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPX3.html) 
[JSP library](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/index.html) 
[JSTL documentation 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html)  
[JSTL library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/)

Comment: It wouldn't be as easy with ajax call from javascript to java, would it? I would need to make a Json out of a Java's `ArrayList` first.

Answer (score 0):

Have Java generate an .html file; open it in the browser.

You can open the default system browser on a webpage using
 [Desktop.open()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29). It allows you to open any file with the default application associated with its file type on the system.

The .html file would have the java-generated data, and can reference JS libraries in the web or in the local filesystem. You can even add a refresh button (or timeout) to check for updated information.

Of course, JSPs or other technologies would work; but those require a server running your application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Direct Web Remoting(DWR).
DWR is a Java library that enables Java on the server and JavaScript in a browser to interact and call each other as simply as possible.

DWR is Easy Ajax for Java

It consists of two main parts:

```
Code to allow JavaScript to retrieve data from a servlet-based web server using Ajax principles.
A JavaScript library that makes it easier for the web site developer to dynamically update the web page with the retrieved data.
```

check out the link-

```
[DWR][1]
```

And demo example is given here-
[DWR chat example](http://www.packtpub.com/article/chatroom-application-using-dwr-java-framework)

Answer (score 0):

HTML is the place to start. JSP can help you generate HTML. Find how to dynamically create images from your data with Java. If that is not enough, read about JSON, Ajax, jquery, and add some JavaScript.